# Wider column in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Hi I'm working with RoR and ActiveAdmin, I have a table with different values one of then is the price, something like: 0,030 €, the problem is that in the table I see it like:

```
0,030 
€
```

And I want to have it in the same row, all the prices are as long as that one(0,xxx €). So any idea about how to make a wider column? Thanks

Comment: [read this](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/63)

Answer (score 1):

This can likely be fixed through CSS alone.

In `/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss` (or equivalent) target the column with the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child) selector and apply a `white-space` restriction to prevent the wrapping.

For example, if it's the 2nd column you can do something like this

```
td:nth-child(2) {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

An example of this can be seen at the link below. Notice the first column wraps, while the 2nd column is restricted to a single line (no break on the whitespace).

http://jsfiddle.net/YLHBE/

You will likely have to target the column/table a bit more explicitly than the generic example above, since the above will apply the styling to the 2nd column of every table the stylesheet applies to.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! but it doesn't work.. I have: profitable_routes{
  width: 100px;  
  td {
    border: 1px solid;
    &:nth-child(7) {
     white-space: nowrap;
    }
  }
}

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it with:  div style: "width:130%%; height:100%%; background-color:lightgreen;" do.... because is the price is positive i want it to be green and if is negative it should be red. Changing this value width:130%% it it be longer or shorter.

Comment: You can up-vote this answer if it helped you. You can additionally accept this answer if it solved your problem. If you solved the issue on your own, you should consider adding the details of your solution (mentioned in your comment above) as an answer to this question, and accept that answer.